# Django translation creates po and mo files, but fails in translation and displays translation placeholders

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I am using Django 1.6.5 with `virtualenv` (Vitrual Environment) and `apache2`

I have following `settings.py` structure:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tr_TR'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'wm_lang'
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/home/mustafa/python/myproject/locale'
)

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

LANGUAGES = (
    ('tr', _(u'Türkçe')),
    ('en', _(u'English')),
)
```

I have a template file looks like that

```
{% extends .... %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>{% trans 'Hosgeldin' %}</h2>
....
....
```

I run following to create `po` files

```
django-admin.py makemessages  --locale=tr --locale=en
```

which creates following files

```
/home/mustafa/python/myproject/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
/home/mustafa/python/myproject/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

I Apply translation strings so my `django.po` translation files look like that

#### en:

```
#: templates/websitesi/index.html:6
msgid "Hosgeldin"
msgstr "Welcome, that is a test"
```

#### tr:

```
#: templates/websitesi/index.html:6
msgid "Hosgeldin"
msgstr "Hoşgeldiniz, bu bir deneme"
```

Then I compile them with

```
django-admin.py compilemessages
```

and django creates `django.mo` files near `django.po` files for both languages.

But when I visit the page, I see `Hosgeldin` (translation placeholder) instead of translated text.

Writing {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} to template displays selected language code. When my address is `someadress/en`, language code displayed as `en`...

What am I missing?

UPDATE: This is a section of my *root* `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/docs/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('websitesi.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),  # This is my home page
                         ....
                         ....
```

Then I  go to `my_local_server/` or `my_local_server/tr` or `my_local_server/en` to test but it all fails in translation.

When I go to admin via `my_local_server/tr/admin` or `my_local_server/en/admin`, django trqnslations works just fine.

Comment: The correct language code is being set?

What does {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} displays?

Comment: Just checking, but did you restart the dev server after running compilemessages?

Comment: @GuilhermeVierno {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} displayed the correcty.

Comment: @JoniBekenstein I am using apache2.

Comment: try language codes like tr_TR/ en_US(just for test)

Comment: Then, did you try restarting apache2? Also, what url are you using to test english translation? LocaleMiddleware will do its thing if it finds a language code in the url, so you would have to use some url like /en/home/

Comment: Yes I restarted it. I update my question

Comment: @ruddra I tried it with no success

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, it turns out to be a typo, as expected.

In `settings.py`

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/home/mustafa/python/myproject/locale'
)
```

But Django expects [`LOCALE_PATHS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#locale-paths) to be a **tuple**, so adding a comma solved the issue...

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/home/mustafa/python/myproject/locale',
)
```